# Radar shape - radarchart js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, radar-chart

I have a problem with radar. I can't get the correct shape.

```
var data = [
          [
            {axis:"1",value:0.85},
            {axis:"2",value:0.75},
            {axis:"3",value:0.75},
            {axis:"4",value:0.9},
            {axis:"5",value:0.4},
  {axis:"6",value:0.4}  
          ]
        ];

var color = d3.scale.ordinal();

var radarChartOptions = {
    w: width,
    h: height,
    margin: margin,
    maxValue: 1,
    levels: 10,
    roundStrokes: true,
    color: color
};
RadarChart(".radarChart", data, radarChartOptions);
```

Now I have something like this

[image: what I have now]

https://codepen.io/raju_wk/pen/RwWBpJy

and I want to have something like this

[image: what I want to have]

Comment: It... kind of feels like you're in the middle of figuring this out all on your own? You have a shape, it doesn't match what you expected, I assume you're now going through the docs to see what you may have missed? Knowing literally nothing about d3 and radar charts, I was still able to turn this into https://i.imgur.com/caF3AIa.png just by adding some reset values to each axis because I know JS. So... what have you tried so far to get your desired chart?

Comment: Yes but you have 12 points not 6, I want to achieve it without adding more points

Comment: radar plots are a polygon, though: how would you get a star if you don't have data points that effect a star shaped hull?